# SPARQL limit result of only one variable

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to query wikidata to retrieve artworks, their material characteristics and the artistic movement they are associated with. Each resulting record can have a number of movements/materials associated with (as an artwork can be classified as belonging to two movements at the same time, or with different materials).

I would like to retrieve for each artwork only one of the movement/material associated with, as not to have duplicate lines in the results to manually remove afterwards.

How can I achieve such result using only SPARQL?

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel ?movementLabel ?materialLabel WHERE {
  
  ?artwork wdt:P31 wd:Q3305213 ;
           wdt:P571 ?time ;
           wdt:P18 ?image .
  
OPTIONAL {
    ?artwork wdt:P170 ?creator 
    }
OPTIONAL {
    ?artwork wdt:P135 ?movement.
    }

OPTIONAL {
    ?artwork wdt:P186 ?material.
    }  

FILTER(?time > "1870-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime)

SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } # Helps get the label in your language, if not, then en language
  
  }

LIMIT 100
```

I tried to use COUNT and HAVING (`HAVING (COUNT(?material) < 2)`) to limit the result, but with such method I get a timeout. Is there any other way?

Comment: @ValerioCocchi since when is there a default aggregate function in SPARQL? It clearly will lead to an error by a standard SPARQL engine or I misunderstand something

Comment: indeed I verified and I got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SAMPLE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregateRestrictions), which picks an arbitrary value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel (SAMPLE(?movementLabel) AS ?movementLabel_sample) (SAMPLE(?materialLabel) AS ?materialLabel_sample)
WHERE {
  
  {
    SELECT ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel ?movementLabel ?materialLabel
    WHERE {
      
      VALUES ?artwork { wd:Q728373 wd:Q720602 } # remove this line to query all artworks
  
      ?artwork wdt:P31 wd:Q3305213 ;
               wdt:P571 ?time ;
               wdt:P18 ?image .
  
      OPTIONAL { ?artwork wdt:P170 ?creator . }
      OPTIONAL { ?artwork wdt:P135 ?movement . }
      OPTIONAL { ?artwork wdt:P186 ?material. }  

      FILTER(?time > "1870-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime) 
      
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } # Helps get the label in your language, if not, then en language
      
    } 
  }
 
}
GROUP BY ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel
LIMIT 100
```

---

But if your only concern is

> not to have duplicate lines in the results to manually remove afterwards

you could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) to get one line per artwork, with multiple values per cell:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?movementLabel; separator=", ") AS ?movementLabels) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?materialLabel; separator=", ") AS ?materialLabels)
WHERE {

  {
    SELECT ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel ?movementLabel ?materialLabel
    WHERE {

      VALUES ?artwork { wd:Q728373 wd:Q720602 } # remove this line to query all artworks

      ?artwork wdt:P31 wd:Q3305213 ;
               wdt:P571 ?time ;
               wdt:P18 ?image .

      OPTIONAL { ?artwork wdt:P170 ?creator . }
      OPTIONAL { ?artwork wdt:P135 ?movement . }
      OPTIONAL { ?artwork wdt:P186 ?material. }  

      FILTER(?time > "1870-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime) 
      
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } # Helps get the label in your language, if not, then en language

    } 
  }

}
GROUP BY ?artwork ?image ?time ?creatorLabel
LIMIT 100
```

(If there can be multiple images, times, or creators, you could do the same for these properties, too.)

Comment: great, thanks! I was not aware of SAMPLE! I generally use concat but this time I just wanted a single unit of information per retrieved record